# Why does my app crashes when I tap "Save Image" option on UIActivityViewController?

Tags: swift, uikit, uiactivityviewcontroller, uipreviewaction

So, in the 3D Touch peek controller, I have this computed var where I setup the UIPreviewAction:

```
override lazy var previewActionItems: [UIPreviewActionItem] = {

    let save = UIPreviewAction.init(title: "Share Image", style: UIPreviewAction.Style.default, handler: { (action, controller) in
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: self.view.bounds.size)
        let imageAux = renderer.image { ctx in
            self.view.drawHierarchy(in: self.view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
        self.delegate!.shareImage(image: imageAux, url: self.data.url)
    })

    return [save]
}()
```

and in the delegate controller I have this method to present the UIActivityViewController:

```
func shareImage(image: UIImage, url: String) {

    if let data = image.pngData() {
        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let filename = paths[0].appendingPathComponent(url)
        try? data.write(to: filename)
    }

    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [image] , applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

everything works fine, i can share with any apps, and can store using the File Explore, but if I press "Save Image", the app crashes. Looks like I need gallery permission, but I don't know how to implement it in the UIPreviewAction to check if I have the permission or not, so that if I do it saves, and if I do not it asks for permission.

Answer (score 2):

Add new records in your new InfoPlist.strings file.

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>

<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
```

delete your app from simulator and run again.

Comment: Works! Thanks. Can you link me any documentation or guide about that?

Comment: Welcome,  i will attach a link.